# How to center text title within Flexbox div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I'm having issues with the centering the title hello world. I want the title to be inside the white white container but I want it to take up it's own line and have the images below the title. I tried solving this by giving the title a class and change it's display property to that of a block but that did not work. I also tried adding a div container outside but that did not work either, at least I didn't manage to make it work. Any suggestions?

CODEPEN:

https://codepen.io/mmartinb/pen/wzozVX

```css
.parenttwo {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parenttwo container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center"> Hello World</h1>
  <img src="http://www.onepagemania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Untitled-12.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://michaelacevedo.com/images/portfolio/sprk-crtv-branding.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.niceoneilike.com/webdesign-inspiration/1572_1_bartek.wojtyca.pl-webdesign-inspiration-website-clean-creative.jpg?m=1364289144" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.designlicks.com/uploads/licks/656x413/21084_20150316015538000000.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.niceoneilike.com/webdesign-inspiration/2294_1_madebydaryl.co.uk-webdesign-inspiration-website-clean-creative.jpg?m=1371803382" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/submissions/2015/07/55b88b065ec9a.jpeg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use flexbox, just make the heading 100% wide

```
.parenttwo .text-center {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jrVJWb)

```css
.parenttwo {
  max-width:1000px;
  min-height:500px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parenttwo .text-center {
  width: 100%;
}

.item1{
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.parentthree {
  max-width:1000px;
  min-height:500px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
     #aboutmetext{
        width:640px;
        margin:0 0 20px 0;
        text-align:center;
        }
  .parent{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1150px){
  .item1{
    width: 85%;
  }
}

.text-center{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parenttwo container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center"> Hello World</h1>
  <img src="http://www.onepagemania.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Untitled-12.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://michaelacevedo.com/images/portfolio/sprk-crtv-branding.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.niceoneilike.com/webdesign-inspiration/1572_1_bartek.wojtyca.pl-webdesign-inspiration-website-clean-creative.jpg?m=1364289144" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.designlicks.com/uploads/licks/656x413/21084_20150316015538000000.jpg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.niceoneilike.com/webdesign-inspiration/2294_1_madebydaryl.co.uk-webdesign-inspiration-website-clean-creative.jpg?m=1371803382" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
  <img src="http://www.awwwards.com/awards/submissions/2015/07/55b88b065ec9a.jpeg" alt="Thumbnail1" class="item1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a width so it can span the whole line:

```
h1.text-center{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width:100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrWRxr

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove *all* the flex styles from `.parenttwo` and display:block like you suggested:

```
.parenttwo {
  max-width:1000px;
  min-height:500px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  display:block;
}
```